# How do I show a `DestinationType=NATIVE_URI` image from iOS in cordova app

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm looking at `cordova.plugin.camera` and it now offers a `DestinationType=NATIVE_URI` setting, but I'm not sure how I use this in a cordova App.

> here is an example from: [How to access image from native URI (assets-library) in Cordova for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31548925/how-to-access-image-from-native-uri-assets-library-in-cordova-for-ios)

```
resolveLocalFileSystemURL('assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=711B4C9D-97D6-455A-BC43-C73059A5C3E8&ext=JPG', function(fileEntry) {
    fileEntry.file(function(file) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function(event) {
            console.log(event.target.result.byteLength);
        };
        console.log('Reading file: ' + file.name);
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    });
});
```

I assume that I will use `cordova.plugin.file`to read the file referenced by a NATIVE_URI like `'assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=711B4C9D-97D6-455A-BC43-C73059A5C3E8&ext=JPG'`

But how do I show that JPG file in the cordova app as an `IMG.src`? Something like this:

```
//<img ng-src="{{myImageSrc}}">
myImageSrc = 'assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=711B4C9D-97D6-455A-BC43-C73059A5C3E8&ext=JPG'
myImageSrc = 'cdvfile://localhost/asset/asset.JPG?id=711B4C9D-97D6-455A-BC43-C73059A5C3E8&ext=JPG'
// or use cordova.plugin.file to write image to 
// cordova.file.applicationStorageDirectory, then
myImageSrc = 'file:////var/mobile/Applications/<UUID>/Library/...'
```

Comment: if I do #3, copy file from `NATIVE_URI` to `cordova.file.*`, then I can successfully do `IMG.src=[cordova file path]` in my cordova app. But is there a way to use the `NATIVE_URI` directly?

Comment: BUT, one caveat: `PHAsset.localIdentifier="0A929779-BFA0-4C1C-877C-28F353BB0EB3/L0/001"`, but cordova only finds the NATIVE_URI if I slice off the `/L0/001`. Why is this?

Comment: For me the workaround explained here works: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37883692/2050333

Comment: I ended up adding a Cordova/swift method to grab the DataURI for the asset. The advantage is that `WkWebView` has no problems with DataURIs, but cannot read from the local file system. And the added performance of downsized DataURIs + WkWebView was worth the effort.